# MySQL - when adding an INNER JOIn - this removed specific items

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to query a product stock take to send to a customer.

When I add in the following INNER JOIN which is currently hashed out below it will remove the majority of data.

```
USE [database];
SELECT 
    distinct products.products_id,
    products.products_status,
    products_description.products_name, 
    products.products_model, 
    products.products_price, 
    products.products_cost, 
    products_stock_location.quantity, 
    stock_location.stock_location_name 

FROM 
    products
INNER JOIN products_stock_location ON products.products_id=products_stock_location.products_id
INNER JOIN products_description ON products.products_id=products_description.products_id
#INNER JOIN products_with_attributes_stock ON products.products_id=products_with_attributes_stock.products_id
INNER JOIN stock_location ON products_stock_location.stock_locations_id=stock_location_id
;
```

I suspect its taking the items which have attributes and only displaying them.

Is there a way to display both?

Comment: Use a LEFT instead of INNER join.

Comment: If joined table does not contain rows which matches the row in "more upper in joining tree" table then this row won't be returned at all. Use LEFT JOIN in this case, starting from the most upper table which may not contain matched rows. In your case - only problematic table (the next table is joined not to problematic table, so it is not in the same joining branch).

Comment: Thanks both. The problem with this database, it has been designed in such an odd way. I have changed the hashed line to LEFT JOIN. which allows the items without attributes to show, but it will not sure the items with attributes.

I think I need use something like FULL JOIN however I know that MySQL doesn't allow the use of FULL JOIN. Any tips?